# How do I get a mach_port_t that corresponds to a std::thread?

Tags: multithreading, macos

Given a std::thread, how do I get the corresponding mach_port_t? I am basically looking for an equivalent of `pthread_mach_thread_np()` which gets a mach_port_t from a pthread_t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::thread::native_handle()` to get the `pthread_t`, then pass that to `pthread_mach_thread_np()`